# Why is electrical stress higher on the insulator string near the transmission conductor?

Tags: voltage, transmission-line

From my observations, it is because of the electric field around the conductor. As we go far from the conductor, the electric field starts decrease. That is why there is also unequal voltage distribution along all the strings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at time dependent dielectric breakdown, time to breakdown is inversely related to electric field: time to breakdown decreases as the electric field increases.  The exact function of that dependency depends on the dielectric properties and conduction mechanisms such as tunneling when the electric field approaches breakdown.  If the electric field is uniform across the dielectric, breakdown will be intrinsic.  Defects in the dielectric may cause a higher electric field at the defect and breakdown at the defect.   If the geometries are such that the electric field is higher at the connector, then that is where breakdown will occur.

If you are dealing with RF, then determining electric field isn't trivial.  Breakdown mechanisms are depended on movement of electrons and holes through the dielectric, not directly on electron movement through the conductors.

If the geometries of your conductors and insulators look something like this,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3tLiR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you approach insulator breakdown, the resistance parallel to the capacitance becomes significant.  As you increase the frequency, the impedance of the inductance becomes significant and the impedance of the capacitance is lower.  Thus, the highest electric field tends to be the shortest path between the transmission and ground.

Comment: What is the question you are attempting to answer?

Comment: @Math That highest electrical stress does correspond to the highest electric field,. The question is worded in generalities.  If higher electric stress doesn't imply dielectric breakdown, then how does one know the stress is higher?  If one assumes the stress is higher because the electric field is higher, then this seems to beg the question.